# RoutedEventHandler on Button.Click function in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, click

i have this code :

```
button.Click += clickFunction();

private void clickFunction(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        // do something
}
```

I am pretty sure it should work, i've done this few times, it is usually how button.Click works. 
But this time, i have an error which say that i can't put a void function in a button.Click. It says i should use a RoutedEventHandler.

Am i not supposed to be able to use a void function? What is a RoutedEventHandler?

Thanks

Comment: `RoutedEventHandler` is a type of `Click` event. You have a typo with brackets `clickFunction();`, have a look at [how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to delete the brackets:

```
button.Click += clickFunction;
```